# Code which actually uses the "\a", "\f", and "\v" escape sequences?

Tags: printing, terminal, ascii

If it weren't for the obligatory listings of escape sequences in textbooks, I'd be unaware of the ASCII characters denoted by the escape sequences "\a", "\f", and "\v" (denoting "bell", "form feed", and "vertical tab".)  Or at least as unaware as I am about the esoteric ASCII control characters like "File Separator", "Data Link Escape" and "End of Medium" that fill up much of the first 32 slots in the ASCII character table.

Are there programs and systems which actually make heaving use of the more uncommon escape sequences given by the C language and its descendants?  For exmaple, if the new crop of programming languages were to drop "\v" notation, would anyone care?  Besides the obvious use in printing, is "\f" used?  Beyond making a terminal beep, what about "\a"?  Are these routinely supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating the escape sequence, which is used by the compiler, with the character, which is used the program (and perhaps passed on to other programs).

Your question, though relevant, is a bit late. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) has already dropped '\v'. Funny, I never noticed. But, not [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx) or [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Never noticed that, either.